# TreeNode - PrimeNG: How to Remove a node from tree?

Tags: angular, typescript, tree, primeng, boost-propertytree

[image]

I have a tree and if I select two nodes they are saved correctly, but if I later decide to delete only one node of the two previously selected, both are deleted. How can I delete only one? this is the part of the code where I check for unselected nodes. The problem is the delete, but I don't know how to do it. Consider that the selected nodes are passed into a map -> functions <with key / value>

```
nodeUnselect(event) {
    if (this.dialogDate) {
      this.selectedNode.push(event.node);
      if (event.node.parent) {
        this.selectedNode.push(event.node.parent);
      }
    } else {
      if (event.node.parent) {
        if (this.userData.functions && event.node.data && event.node.data.functionFK) {
          delete this.userData.functions[event.node.data.functionFK];
        }
      } else {
        if (event.node.children && event.node.children.length) {
          for (const childNode of event.node.children) {
            if (this.userData.functions && childNode.data && childNode.data.functionFK) {
              delete this.userData.functions[childNode.data.functionFK];
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

If you need more code I'll post it

Comment: Why is your post in all-bold? Highlighting only has an effect if you apply it carefully.

Comment: I made a mistake!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is may help some one,

```
deleteNode(node:any) : void {
    if (node.parent != null) {
      console.log(node.buildingId)
      console.log(node.parent.children.indexOf(node))
      node.parent.children.splice(node.parent.children.indexOf(node), 1)  
      
    }}
```